# How to get margin in css when border to box?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have two `div` in my page. When I apply a border to these boxes, they get margin from top; but when no border is applied, the boxes are displayed with no margin. Why?

```css
.header {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.menu {
  background-color: green;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>title</h1>
</div>
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Comment: the margin is on the h1 and is still there, it just changes what the margin is spacing from. Not sure what effect you actually want but try adding to h1 { margin: 0; padding: 1rem; }

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:auto` to your `.header` div.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/pqb9z5mn/)**

And check out [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) while you're at it.